# How to get an async lambda to await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have the following function:

```
public async Task<List<UserViewModel>> Get(string role, string nameText, int offset, int number) {
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    if (role != "") {
    new List<User>(await userManager.GetUsersForClaimAsync(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("role", role)));

    }

    List<Task<UserViewModel>> data = users
    .Skip(offset)
    .Take(number)
    .Select(async (user) => {
        return await identityUserToUserViewModel(user); ;
    }).ToList();


    return data;
}
```

which calls

```
async Task<UserViewModel> identityUserToUserViewModel(User user) {
    var principal = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    return new UserViewModel()
    {
        Email = user.Email,
        PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
        Location = locationRepository.GetForUser(user.Id),
        Name = user.Name,
        Role = principal.Where(Claim => Claim.Type == "role").ToList().FirstOrDefault().Value,
        sub = user.Id
    };
}
```

However, this function gives an error of 
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Models.ViewModel.UserViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.ViewModel.UserViewModel>'`

I understand that the async lambda is converting it back into a task, but I can't figure out how to -not- have that happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.Select(async (user) => {
    return await identityUserToUserViewModel(user);
})
```

Because making something `async` actually means that the result gets wrapped in a `Task`, this actually has the same result as the following:

```
.Select((user) => {
    return identityUserToUserViewModel(user);
})
```

So the result of that call is an `IEnumerable<Task<UserViewModel>>`. So converting it to a list will give you a list of tasks, not a list of UserViewModels.

If you now want to await *all* those tasks and just return a list of view models, then you can use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netstandard-2.1). It will await all the tasks it gets passed, and fortunately return an array of all the tasks’ results:

```
IEnumerable<Task<UserViewModel>> dataTasks = users
    .Skip(offset)
    .Take(number)
    .Select(identityUserToUserViewModel);

UserViewModel[] data = Task.WhenAll(dataTasks);

return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the following code returns a `Task<UserViewModel>` for each call

```
.Select(async (user) => {
    return await identityUserToUserViewModel(user);
```

You could wrap the LINQ expression with `await Task.WhenAll(...)` this returns an array of `UserViewModel` that can be converted to a `List<UserViewModel>`